# Why does R ignore binwidth, bins in ggplot geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a histogram of the values in one column of a dataframe. I try setting the bin or binwidth args but to no avail. R while building the plot says, "Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad".

`ggplot(data=subset(flights, Distance < quantile(flights$Distance, 0.75)))+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Distance), stat='count', binwidth=100)`

The variable to be plotted is a vector of integers, distances for flights.

I've tried changing the data type to numeric from integer.

`flights$Distance <- as.numeric(as.character(flights$Distance))`

I tried it on a smaller sample and get the same message.

`df <- data.frame(Distance=c(2,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,6,7,5,4,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,5))`

`ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=Distance), stat='count', binwidth=2)`

Why ggplot ignoring the two possible bin arguments?

Comment: Just remove `stat='count'` from the call to `geom_histogram`. `geom_histogram` uses `stat="bin"` by default and that's the stat you want for a histogram.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) will be of help:

> Visualise the distribution of a single continuous variable by dividing
>   the x axis into bins and counting the number of observations in each
>   bin. Histograms (geom_histogram) display the count with bars;
>   frequency polygons (geom_freqpoly), display the counts with lines.
>   Frequency polygons are more suitable when you want to compare the
>   distribution across a the levels of a categorical variable. stat_bin
>   is suitable only for continuous x data. If your x data is discrete,
>   you probably want to use stat_count.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(data = df, aes(x=Distance), binwidth = 3) +
                 stat_count()
```

Comment: `stat_count()` is superfluous here if you want a histogram. (Although with integer data, `stat_count` will give you the equivalent of a histogram with binwidth=1.) If you add, say, `fill="red"` to `geom_histogram`, you'll see that `stat_count()` is putting a bar plot on top of the histogram. You just can't see it because `geom_histogram` and `stat_count` use the same default fill color.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to see how `stat_count()` is putting a bar plot "on top off" of the histogram? I tried to set `fill = "red"` but didn't notice anything.

Comment: Ah, it's because you put the data and aesthetic inside `geom_histogram` instead of in the main ggplot call. So `stat_count()` is doing absolutely nothing, because it doesn't know about the data frame or the aesthetic. Sorry, I didn't look carefully enough at your code. If you put the data frame and `aes` in the main ggplot call, you'll see both sets of bars.